# cakephp shell uses not working

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, plugins, model

I use `public $uses = array('PluginA.ModelClass1');` to load the plugin model class in shell. And when I run the shell in command line, I got the following error:

```
Mac:Console charles$ ./cake PluginA.do_something test CAMPAIGN -c 1
Notice Error: Undefined property: DoSomethingShell::$ModelClass1 in [/Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php, line 443]

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function exists() on a non-object in /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Plugin/PluginA/Console/Command/DoSomethingShell.php on line 91
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Console/cake.php:0
PHP   2. ShellDispatcher::run() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Console/cake.php:37
PHP   3. ShellDispatcher->dispatch() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:68
PHP   4. Shell->runCommand() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:200
PHP   5. DoSomethingShell->test() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php:389

Fatal error: Call to a member function exists() on a non-object in /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Plugin/PluginA/Console/Command/DoSomethingShell.php on line 91

Call Stack:
    0.0003     228248   1. {main}() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Console/cake.php:0
    0.0010     314344   2. ShellDispatcher::run() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Console/cake.php:37
    0.0153    2075240   3. ShellDispatcher->dispatch() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:68
    0.0201    2416216   4. Shell->runCommand() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:200
    0.0262    3250056   5. DoSomethingShell->test() /Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php:389

Fatal Error Error: Call to a member function exists() on a non-object in [/Users/charles/Workspace/PHP/ProjectA/app/Plugin/PluginA/Console/Command/DoSomethingShell.php, line 91]
```

The shell and loaded model class are all in the plugin `PluginA`. And in `ModelClass1`, there is a method called `exists()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: I tried the same setup and it seems to work. Can you paste more code from the shell?

Comment: Are you in /app or /app/Console?  Try cd'ing back to /app and executing ./Console/cake PluginA.do_something test CAMPAIGN -c 1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! And the issue is gone after I update my PHP. Maybe I didn't set up the PHP and cakePHP correctly.